# Swift decrypt AES CCM message

Tags: swift, encryption, aes, cryptoswift, apple-cryptokit

I'm trying to decrypt a message in Swift that is sent from a device which I've connected via Bluetooth.

I'm trying to make a swift implementation of this article:

https://www.makinolo.com/blog/2023/10/08/connecting-to-zwift-play-controllers/

I've created a symmetric key through the following steps:

```
let privateKey = P256.KeyAgreement.PrivateKey()
var message = "RideOn".data(using: .utf8)!
message.append(Data([0x01, 0x09]))
let publicKey = privateKey.publicKey
message.append(publicKey.rawRepresentation)
/// sent to peripheral
```

I receive their public key and create the shared secret

```
        let rideOn = "RideOn".data(using: .utf8)!

        guard value.starts(with: rideOn) else {
            logger.error("no ride on?")
            return
        }

        let key = value.dropFirst(8)

        guard let publicKey = try? P256.KeyAgreement.PublicKey(rawRepresentation: key) else {
            logger.debug("wrong key?")
            return
        }

        let salt = key + privateKey.publicKey.rawRepresentation

        guard let sharedSecret = try? privateKey.sharedSecretFromKeyAgreement(with: publicKey) else {
            logger.debug("no shared secret")
            return
        }
        let symmetricKey = sharedSecret.hkdfDerivedSymmetricKey(using: SHA256.self, salt: salt, sharedInfo: Data(), outputByteCount: 36)
```

I start receiving messages, but I cannot get the messages to decode. These steps do not seem to work for iOS, because of a difference nonce maybe?

```
For decryption you need to extract the 3 parts of the message and call the AES-CCM decrypt function with:

- The AES mode, which is aes-256-ccm
- The IV (initialization Vector) also called nonce (number used once) which is an 8 byte array whose 4 first bytes are the 4 last bytes of the HKDF symmetric key, followed by the 4 bytes of the counter you have received in the message.
The IV / nonce length, which is 8 bytes
- The received MIC, so the algorithm can compare his own calculated MIC with the one provided and authenticate the message
- The received message (only the remaining bytes in the message after stripping the counter and the MIC)
```

I've tried the following:

Using cryptoswift:

```
        let nonceData = symmetricKey.withUnsafeBytes { Data(Array($0)) }[...3] + value[...3]
        let tag = value.suffix(4)
        var value = value
        value = value.dropFirst(4)
        value.removeLast(4)

        do {
            let aes = try AES(key: symmetricKey.withUnsafeBytes { Array($0) }, blockMode: CCM(iv: [UInt8](nonceData), tagLength: 4, messageLength: value.count), padding: .zeroPadding)
            let result = try aes.decrypt([UInt8](value))

            print("Result: \(result)")
        } catch {
            logger.debug("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
```

using CryptoKit

```
        do {
            let nonce = try AES.GCM.Nonce(data: nonceData)

            let sealedBox = try AES.GCM.SealedBox(nonce: nonce, ciphertext: value, tag: tag)
            let result = try AES.GCM.open(sealedBox, using: symmetricKey)

        } catch {
            logger.debug("\(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
```

I think there is a problem with creating the Nonce, but no real clue, not really familiar with encryption/decryption.

This is a couple of the messages I receive:

```
Own private key: [36, 147, 90, 234, 66, 250, 58, 153, 187, 163, 237, 184, 100, 91, 99, 35, 139, 69, 181, 239, 250, 214, 164, 116, 118, 58, 95, 218, 28, 25, 111, 105]
Own public key: [34, 76, 142, 17, 129, 101, 252, 53, 92, 200, 144, 34, 20, 43, 115, 100, 181, 27, 19, 176, 145, 253, 34, 241, 74, 107, 125, 254, 130, 146, 169, 65, 118, 6, 199, 146, 89, 20, 47, 233, 101, 134, 76, 192, 61, 167, 135, 89, 100, 140, 56, 63, 3, 117, 57, 52, 136, 220, 38, 44, 119, 8, 110, 201]
Click key: [247, 134, 157, 189, 154, 129, 53, 47, 254, 165, 164, 49, 150, 55, 151, 75, 7, 182, 85, 194, 28, 198, 177, 153, 128, 75, 32, 50, 155, 204, 225, 201, 215, 241, 81, 246, 9, 222, 89, 81, 11, 190, 74, 214, 117, 41, 155, 227, 87, 41, 120, 34, 141, 227, 83, 85, 22, 246, 115, 0, 65, 174, 194, 48]
Salt: [247, 134, 157, 189, 154, 129, 53, 47, 254, 165, 164, 49, 150, 55, 151, 75, 7, 182, 85, 194, 28, 198, 177, 153, 128, 75, 32, 50, 155, 204, 225, 201, 215, 241, 81, 246, 9, 222, 89, 81, 11, 190, 74, 214, 117, 41, 155, 227, 87, 41, 120, 34, 141, 227, 83, 85, 22, 246, 115, 0, 65, 174, 194, 48]

After pressing click, a couple of the messages:
[21, 0, 0, 0, 248, 68, 228, 177, 135, 249, 158, 236, 165]
[22, 0, 0, 0, 78, 244, 116, 18, 109, 111, 238, 175, 86]
[23, 0, 0, 0, 122, 90, 33, 237, 14, 237, 234]
[24, 0, 0, 0, 139, 66, 8, 195, 217, 18, 234]
[25, 0, 0, 0, 3, 247, 14, 46, 58, 88, 71]
```

Comment: Can you post complete sample data so that a repro is possible? Your private and public key, the public key of the device and the message. Of course, these must be consistent for the repro to be successful.

Comment: I've update the message data and started a new run, so messages are also updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the following points in your code:

- Although the salt seems to be correctly determined in the code with

  ```swift
  let salt = key + privateKey.publicKey.rawRepresentation
  ```

  in your sample data it only appears to consist of the public key of the device side.
- The nonce seems to be determined incorrectly. According to the instructions, the nonce consists of the last 4 bytes of the HKDF key and the first 4 bytes of the message, i.e. it should be something like:

  ```swift
  let nonceData = symmetricKey.withUnsafeBytes { Data(Array($0)) }.suffix(4) + valueMsg.prefix(4)
  ```
- Also the AES key seems to be determined incorrectly. The AES key consists of the first 32 bytes (corresponds to AES-256) of the 36 byte HKDF key, i.e. it should be something like:

  ```swift
  let aesKey = symmetricKey.withUnsafeBytes { Data(Array($0)) }.prefix(32)
  ```
- In the AES/CCM decryption with CryptoSwift, the tag does not seem to be taken into account. The correct way would be to pass the concatenation `valueCtTag` of ciphertext and tag to `decrypt()`, where `valueCtTag` is something like:

  ```swift
  let valueCtTag = valueMsg.dropFirst(4)
  ```

  As `messageLength` specify: `valueCtTag.count - 4`, as `tagLength` apply: `4`.
  Regarding the padding: It should not be `.zeroPadding`, but `.noPadding`.
  See also the [AES/CCM sample](https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/CryptoSwift/blob/main/Tests/CryptoSwiftTests/AESCCMTests.swift#L419) for tag length 4 from the CryptoSwift tests.

With these changes decryption works for me (as the successful authentication proves).

However, I only verified the shared secret and the HKDF key with the posted Swift code (modified as described above), but not the CCM decryption itself (as I currently do not have an environment with CryptoSwift available).
I have successfully performed the AES/CCM decryption in Python with the parameters determined in the (modified) Swift code, which proves that the ciphertext can *in principle* be successfully decrypted with these parameters using AES/CCM. So if the CCM implementation of CryptoSwift is not buggy, the decryption of the given ciphertext with CryptoSwift should also be successful.

Regarding your CryptoKit decryption: This cannot work because GCM and CCM are different operating modes that are not compatible.

---

Here are the intermediate values that were generated with the (modified) Swift code (apart from the last value `decrypted`, which was determined with Python as mentioned). This should at least make it easier for you to narrow down possible bugs (all values are hex encoded):

```
other public key, hex: f7869dbd9a81352ffea5a4319637974b07b655c21cc6b199804b20329bcce1c9d7f151f609de59510bbe4ad675299be3572978228de3535516f6730041aec230
private key, hex:      24935aea42fa3a99bba3edb8645b63238b45b5effad6a474763a5fda1c196f69
public key, hex:       224c8e118165fc355cc89022142b7364b51b13b091fd22f14a6b7dfe8292a9417606c79259142fe965864cc03da78759648c383f0375393488dc262c77086ec9
salt, hex:             f7869dbd9a81352ffea5a4319637974b07b655c21cc6b199804b20329bcce1c9d7f151f609de59510bbe4ad675299be3572978228de3535516f6730041aec230224c8e118165fc355cc89022142b7364b51b13b091fd22f14a6b7dfe8292a9417606c79259142fe965864cc03da78759648c383f0375393488dc262c77086ec9
shared secret, hex:    a9137e57dd92892464a807b19fa353d5dd39a1b5a1153ae36fb7a86ee75248e5
HKDF key, hex:         211a0ef8a89e5c60962b9c9dd9b7492328c0115a0db840e710b9cace78668cdf8cb25c08
```

For the first message: `[21, 0, 0, 0, 248, 68, 228, 177, 135, 249, 158, 236, 165]`:

```
message, hex:          15000000f844e4b187f99eeca5
counter, hex:          15000000
ciphertext, hex:       f844e4b187
tag, hex:              f99eeca5
ciphertext|tag, hex:   f844e4b187f99eeca5
nonce, hex:            8cb25c0815000000
AES key, hex:          211a0ef8a89e5c60962b9c9dd9b7492328c0115a0db840e710b9cace78668cdf
decrypted, hex:        3708011001
```

Comment: Tnx, followed your steps and it works!